# Given three nxn arrays, produce the output A+B=C where A, B and C are represented as matrices in the output using C programming language

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, matrix, logic

Assume the matrices to be of the form,
[image: Matrices general form]

The required output on stdout using C language should be
[image]

*My code:*

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
     int size, i=0, j=0;
     printf("Enter the size of the array:");
     scanf("%d",&size);
     int A[size][size], B[size][size], C[size][size];   

//Entering the values in A[][]

     printf("enter the elements of Array A:\n");
     for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
         for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
           scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);

//Entering the values in B[][]

     printf("enter the elements of Array B:\n");
     for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
         for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
           scanf("%d",&B[i][j]);

// Calculating C[][]=A[][]+B[][]

     for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
         for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
           C[i][j]=A[i][j]+B[i][j]; 

     i=0;
     j=0;

     while(i<size)
     {
        if( i==size/2)
          printf("%*c%*c\n\n",6*size+1,'+',13*(size-1),'=');

         while(j<size)
           printf("%d\t",A[i][j++]);
         j=0;

         while(j<size)
           printf("%d\t",B[i][j++]);
         j=0; 

         while(j<size)
           printf("%d\t",C[i][j++]);
         j=0;

         printf("\n\n");
         i++;
    }
}
```

But this code only gives the desired output when `size=2`. 
[image: Output when size=2]

But I need a solution which works for all values of `size` entered by the user.

Comment: You should show an example of why it's wrong

Comment: @MadPhysicist .. no the output for size=2 is correct. But i wanted a more generalised code which I got by help from you guys. Check my answer below.. i rectified my code and it gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use a tab (8 columns) to go to the next column, so replace

> ```
> printf("%*c%*c\n\n",6*size+1,'+',13*(size-1),'=');
> ```

by

```
 printf("%*c%*c\n\n",8*size-4,'+',8*size,'=');
```

example :

[image]

of course that supposes all numbers need up to 7 columns

If you want to always have 1 line between each line with numbers modify the *while* to have :

```
  while(i<size)
  {
    if( i==size/2)
      printf("%*c%*c\n",8*size-4,'+',8*size,'=');
    else
      putchar('\n');

    while(j<size)
      printf("%d\t",A[i][j++]);
    j=0;

    while(j<size)
      printf("%d\t",B[i][j++]);
    j=0; 

    while(j<size)
      printf("%d\t",C[i][j++]);
    j=0;

    putchar('\n');
    i++;
  }
```

producing :

[image]

Out of that I encourage you to check *scanf* always return 1 else you do not detect an invalid input

Comment: It is still not giving the desired result. The '+' and '=' signs do not quite fall in the correct place. Also i guess if the size of the matrix is even the the signs fall between two rows whereas if size is odd the =n the signs '+' and '=' must be printed along the middle row.
Hope you get my point.

Comment: @PrateekTewary I removed the example in my answer because S.O. does not respect the spaces, but that works

Comment: BTW what is S.O. ??
Your code now works fine but still placing the signs in between rows when size of matrix is odd is still not possible.

Comment: @PrateekTewary S.O. is **S**tack**O**verflow ;-) I do not understand your remark about when size is odd. I added a picture as you did

Comment: @PrateekTewary finally may be I understood, I edited my answer, look at it

Comment: thanks for the code but I reached that conclusion already after making a few modifications to my code as you suggested but.. The '+' and '=' sign specifically have to be in the middle of the two matrices.
For instance, if size=2, the '+'  and '=' should lie between row 1 and row 2
               but, if size=3, the '+' and '='  should lie along the row 2.
I have modified my code and made changes as you suggested while adding some modifications by myself. You can check the code I have given in the answer below. Thanks a lot for your help @bruno .

Comment: @PrateekTewary fine, anyway the **real** correction was to use 8 as I did rather than 6/13 as you did initially, the rest is just details. What about to accept my answer ?

Comment: the question focuses on printing the signs properly and aligning the matrices as well, the purpose which your code does not completely fulfill.
Also to the link you gave I found--
"Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well."
Though I have upvoted you answer. Cheers!

Comment: @PrateekTewary In your question the only example we can see place the + and = **between** the lines and my proposal follows *exactly* that. There is **absolutely nothing** in your question saying in case of odd number of lines + = must be inside the middle line.  You cannot blame me when I fully answer to the question rather than what something hidden in your head. I used time to help you, I do not think I will redo !

Comment: okay @bruno .. my bad. I should've mentioned but i did tell you about the '+' and '=' in the comments though i accept it was not in the question. I have accepted your answer. Cheers man!

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve my question,

```
int size_odd_or_even=size%2;
    int check=1;

    while(i<size)
   {

       if( size_odd_or_even==0 && i==size/2 && check==1)
        {
          printf("\n%*c%*c\n",8*size-4,'+',8*size,'=');
          check=0;
          continue;
        }


       if( size_odd_or_even==1 && i== (int)(size/2) )
         {
               while( j<size-1)
                printf("%d\t",A[i][j++]);
               printf("%d   +   ",A[i][j]);
         }
        else
         {
           while( j<size)
            printf("%d\t",A[i][j++]);
         }
        j=0;


        if( size_odd_or_even==1 && i== (int)(size/2))
         {
               while( j<size-1)
                printf("%d\t",B[i][j++]);
               printf("%d   =   ",B[i][j]);
         }
        else
         {
           while(j<size)
          printf("%d\t",B[i][j++]);
         }
        j=0;


        while(j<size)
            printf("%d\t",Sum[i][j++]);
        j=0;

        if( size_odd_or_even==0 && !(i==size/2-1) )
          printf("\n\n");
        else if(size_odd_or_even==1)
          printf("\n\n");

        i++;
   }
```

This code gives the outputs for `size=4` and `size=5` respectively as,
[image: Output for size=4]
[image: output for size=5]

If this code can be optimised then please do tell.